# argparse change definition of argument

Tags: python, argparse

I set up my argument parser as follows:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--point',help='enter a point (e.g. 2,3,4)')
parser.parse_args('--point=-2,5,6'.split())  #works
parser.parse_args('--point -2,5,6'.split())  #doesn't work :(
```

Is there any way to tell argparse that strings which match the regular expression `r"-\d+.*"` are not options but an argument of an option?

Also note that I *could* do something like this:

```
parser.add_argument('--point',nargs='*')
parser.parse_args('--point -2 5 6'.split())
```

but that's not really how I want it to work.

Comment: I would suggest to force enclosing point arguments in brackets (or whatever seems logical)...

Comment: @jadkik94 -- the most logical braces (to me) are parenthesis -- But those have special meaning in the shell and would have to be escaped ... Plus it makes the code slightly more ugly when splitting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind messing around with argparse internals, argparse already does something very similar to what I want to do.  One of the classes that `ArgumentParser` inherits from has this line in `__init__`

```
import re as _re
...
self._negative_number_matcher = _re.compile(r'^-\d+$|^-\d*\.\d+$')
```

So to get my example to work, we just need to swap out an appropriate regex...

```
parser._negative_number_matcher = re.compile(r'^-\d+|^-\d*\.\d+')
```

Usually I'm not very much in favor of messing around with the internals of a class when they're prefixed by an underscore (as it is implementation dependent and liable to change) -- However, in this case, I think it's probably ok because:

- If argparse changes that variable name, it doesn't hurt, we're just back to the case where "--print -2,3,4" doesn't work again.
- I can't think of any better way to determine if something is a number than regex (I suppose they could try to cast to a float and catch the exception, but if they did that, they wouldn't have a variable named _negative_number_matcher anymore and again, argparse would still work fine except in this corner case where it doesn't do what I want)

Comment: If you stumble across this with a google search -- take a look at the other answers.  They're probably better practice than this answer, but this one does what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I think preprocessing sys.argv is the most straightforward way here. Consider for example:

```
import argparse, re

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--point',help='enter a point (e.g. 2,3,4)')

args = '--point -2,5,6'.split() # or sys.argv

is_list = re.compile(r'^-?[\d,.]+$')
args = ['"%s"' % x if is_list.match(x) else x for x in args]
print parser.parse_args(args)
```

This returns `Namespace(point='"-2,5,6"')` which should be easy to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the [prefix char](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars) so `-` is no longer recognized as indicating the start of an argument. It does look a bit weird but it is useful when negative numbers may appear in the arguments.

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars = '@')
parser.add_argument('@@point',help='enter a point (e.g. 2,3,4)')
args = parser.parse_args('@@point=-2,5,6'.split())  #works
print(args)
# Namespace(point='-2,5,6')

args = parser.parse_args('@@point -2,5,6'.split())  #work also
print(args)
# Namespace(point='-2,5,6')
```

Comment: I didn't think of that (perhaps I should have) -- but my parser has a lot more arguments and it would seem a little silly to break expected usage just for this corner case ... I love argparse, but sometimes I wish it would leave a little more of the internals open so that I could accomplish something like this via subclassing.  (I suppose I could preprocess sys.argv to join arguments like that with an = ...)